# Ubuntu Server Goes Down on client call

Tags: server

I'm running ubuntu server.
It works find on simple get requests. But when I post data to the server it goes down and after few hours it goes live again.
For example: I installed phpmyadmin on the server and created database and when I uploaded sql file for db import it goes down.
Plz Help.
Thanks

Comment: what is your web server ? edit your question  and provide this info.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the webserver(**apache2**) goes down? Ubuntu server is an operating system, which has some pre integrated service. I should check the apache2 log file: `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: Everything goes down(apache, ssh, ftp ...)